Scatterplots predicted values vs data for each feature
I made a polynomial linear regression model with Sklearn with a pipeline (standscaler, polynomial and fit). The model has three features and is polynomial to the degree of 2. I would like make a for each feature a scatterplot with the actual data and a trendline of predicted value; the two other features should remain constant at their (scaled) mean value in these pots. The plot is generated by a function but always an error 'ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names must be in the same order as they were in fit' is given.
What could be wrong in this code?
sel = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3']
df_X = df[sel]
df_Y = df['output']

# Change to numpy array
y = df_Y
X = df_X

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler


# first scale and afterwards do polynomial
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, interaction_only=False, include_bias=False)),
    ('regressor', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True))]) # fit by linear regressor with estimating intercept

pipeline.fit(X, y)

# Function to plot scatter plots with trendline
def plot_with_trendline(X, y, feature_name):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    
    # Calculate mean values of other features
    mean_values = X.mean()
    mean_values = mean_values.drop(feature_name)  # Drop the current feature

    # Generate a range of values for the current feature
    feature_values = np.linspace(X[feature_name].min(), X[feature_name].max(), 100)
    
    # Prepare input for predictions
    X_plot = pd.DataFrame({
        feature_name: feature_values,
        **{k: mean_values[k] for k in mean_values.index}
    })
    
    # Scale the features
    X_scaled = pipeline.named_steps['scaler'].transform(X_plot)
    
    # Transform the scaled features using polynomial features
    X_poly = pipeline.named_steps['poly'].transform(X_scaled)
    
    # Get trendline predictions
    y_trendline = pipeline.named_steps['regressor'].predict(X_poly)
    
    # Scatter plot
    plt.scatter(X[feature_name], y, color='blue', label='Data Points')
    
    # Plot trendline
    plt.plot(feature_values, y_trendline, color='red', label='Trendline', linewidth=2)
    
    plt.xlabel(feature_name)
    plt.ylabel('Target Variable')
    plt.title(f'Scatter Plot of {feature_name} vs. Target Variable')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

# Create scatter plots with trendlines for each feature
for feature in X.columns
    plot_with_trendline(X, y, 'feature')


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share your full error message and traceback. Additionally, please ensure your code sample represents an [mre] - we don't have a copy of df, so the current code will error out.

Since you did not provide a line number for the error, we can only guess. This error is raised, when the columns during training of a model are different to the columns during prediction or evaluation.
